# How to change (and KEEP) appearance of button in Indesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, creative-cloud

I'm creating a simple button that I want to change the colour of when clicked. Currently the appearance changes upon clicking, but the button does not KEEP its new state.

Is it possible to have the button toggle between the desired colours, or can this only be achieved using layers??

Answer (score 1):

There isn't "toggle" buttons by default in InDesign (unless I am wrong). It's easy however to fake them by using a combination of two buttons mutually hiding/displaying each other.
[image: Setting first button to hide himself on click and displays second button]

[image: Setting second button to hide himself on click and displays first button]